# How to add dropdown listview with search on textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to implement this type of dropdown on my page. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: i want this type of drop down listview]

Comment: Check this. https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/drop-down-menu-tutorials-html5-jquery-css3/
And try Googling what you want to do before posting a question. Chances are, someone has already asked that question and it has already been answered.

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: yes im trying bootstrap to do this but it's cant work properly

Comment: I've spend two days googling and searching online to find the solution with no luck that's why I posted a new question here, hoping to get some help from the community as I'am still a learner and new to web designing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `<datalist>` element to take advantage of HTML5's native drop-down menu implementation.

**Working Example:**

```html
<input list="adventure" name="myAdventure" placeholder="Start your search by typing 'Location' or 'Activity'" size="45">

<datalist id="adventure">
  <option value="Location - Azad Kashmir">
  <option value="Location - Balochistan">
  <option value="Location - Chitral / Kalash">
  <option value="Location - Fairy Meadows">
  <option value="Location - Hunza / Gilgit">
  <option value="Location - Islamabad">

  <option value="Activity - Beach">
  <option value="Activity - Cliff Diving">
  <option value="Activity - Cultural Tour">
  <option value="Activity - Desert Safari">
  <option value="Activity - Moutaineering">
  <option value="Activity - Paragliding">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a jQuery plugin, such as [jQuery UI's Autocomplete component](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

> Enables users to quickly find and select from a pre-populated list of values as they type, leveraging searching and filtering.